# Why is &mut Send? How can a thread capture a &mut in safe Rust?

Tags: multithreading, rust, thread-safety

The language [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sync.html) state:

> `&mut T` is `Send` if and only if `T` is `Send`

Can somebody provide a code example of where this is actually relevant?
`thread::spawn` requires its closure to borrow for `'static` lifetime, therefore only statics can be borrowed by a thread closure, but safe Rust doesn't allow `static mut`. Thus, it should not be possible to capture anything in a thread-closure by `&mut` anyway.

In which use-case can a `&mut`'s `Send`-ability be of relevance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `&mut T` should be `Send` on principle (if `T` is `Send`); the implementation shouldn't be disregard simply because you can't construct a safe use-case for it (`unsafe` still exists for a reason).

But there are safe use-cases:

- [`std::thread::scope`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.scope.html) provides a way to execute code in other threads while allowing access to local variables. In the linked documentation a `&mut i32` is used in another thread, and thus requires `Send`.
- It is not `unsafe` to use a `&'static mut T` and `static mut` is not the only way to create one. It can be done safely by using [`Box::leak`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.leak) for example. This should clearly be viable for sending to another thread.
- `async` tasks may want to be `Send` while keeping internal mutable references across `.await` points, and thus require `&mut T` to implement `Send`. This is trivially done all the time whether you realize it or not when writing `async` functions.