# Sync only type makes no sense without Send in rust: You need to move objects across thread boundaries to make it sharable. Is this correct?

Tags: rust

- `std::marker::Sync` : a type is safe to use in a shared ownership model across threads
- `std::marker::Send` : a type is safe to cross thread boundaries

A Sync only type makes no sense. You have to first move the object across thread boundaries to make it usable in a "true" shared context. You cannot share plain old references `&T/&mut T` across thread boundaries because the lifetimes (other than `'static`) come into play.

- What use cases will get covered by having a Sync only type ?
- `Sync` trait seems to be of no value without a `Send` . `Send` is what enables sharing so why was `Sync` trait created ?

Please correct my assumptions if they are wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is &mut Send? How can a thread capture a &mut in safe Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76706994/why-is-mut-send-how-can-a-thread-capture-a-mut-in-safe-rust/) TL;DR: Lifetimes don't prevent sharing references.

Comment: There does not *need* to be a type that is `Sync` but not `Send` for those two traits being different, as there *are* types which are `Send` but not `Sync` (`Cell` for instance), just like `Copy` requires `Clone` but is not equivalent to it.

Comment: But there are some examples of these types, such as [`zipkin::Attached`](https://docs.rs/zipkin/0.3.1/zipkin/struct.Attached.html).

Comment: Or [`MutexGuard`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.MutexGuard.html).